# Angular - how to get properties?

Tags: angular, properties

I'm confused about how to get a property of an Angular element. I'm using Angular Material, and in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) they describe how `mat-button-toggle` has a property called `checked` that signals whether the button is checked or not. So in my head for an element like:

```
<mat-button-toggle id="100"> Button </mat-button-toggle>
```

I should be able to do a

```
let element = document.getElementById("100");
let checked = element.checked;
```

However, the `checked` variable turns up as `undefined`. Why? And how can I programmatically check if the button is checked?

Comment: using property binding/event binding to track state. or using ViewChild

Comment: If you don't want to use ElementRef through, use can use below code

`<mat-button-toggle id="100" value="true" (change)="changes($event)"> Button </mat-button-toggle>`


   use can get value of button
   ` changes($event) {
        console.log($event);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You should never access your Angular elements using "querySelector" (or only as a last resort), instead use view child like this:

**Template:**

```html
<mat-button-toggle #btnToggle> Button </mat-button-toggle>
```

documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

**Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//...

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('btnToggle', { static: false }) btnToggle: matButtonToggle; // remove { static: false } if you're using Angular < 8 

  //....
  ngInit() {
     let checked = this.btnToggle.checked
     console.log(checked);
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. I don't want to *change* the property, the default functionality does that - I want to *read* the state the property is in (f.e. I want to be able to get a list of buttons that are `checked`).

Comment: I litetally wrote "And how can I programmatically check if the button is checked?".

Comment: Well that's how you do it. I don't see where's the problem here?

Comment: You wrote code on how to *change*it. I don't want to change the property, the default functionality does that - I want to read the state the property is in.

Comment: I never wrote code to *change* it. Did you tried the solution?

Comment: @lte__ this is how you read a property. this answer is correct .. what's your case exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

In `Angular` you can access the instance of a component with [Template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var). To declare this kind of variable use `#variableName` in markup.

```
<component #theComponent></component>
```

So, in markup you can read properties of the component.

```
<div>{{theComponent.property}}</div>
```

Or access it in the code with [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator.

```
@ViewChild('theComponent', {static: false}) theComponent : Component;
```

Now you have access to the instance of the `Component` and all of its properties and methods with `theComponent` property.

[Sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsubwz)

When you put `id` in an Angular component, the `document.getElementById` gives you the instance of generated `HtmlElement` of the component and , abviously, there is no `checked` property, so it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:-

```
<mat-button-toggle id="100" [checked]="checkedValue"> Button </mat-button-toggle>
```

> and in your component.ts file:-

You can have a class variable

```
public checkedValue: Boolean = true;
```

Now you can use this "checkedvalue" variable to do any of the programmatical manipulations that you want.

Comment: I want `checked` to continue default behavior, I just want to read it. Is there really no straightforward way to access element properties in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

```
<mat-button-toggle #buttonToggle id="100"> Button </mat-button-toggle>
```

please import **ElementRef**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('buttontoggle', { static: true }) buttonToggle: ElementRef;

//now you can access whole properties 
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.buttonToggle);
}
```